# Chart.js : Module parse failed when using the latest version of chart.js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I've installed Chart.js v4.0.1 to be used in my react project, when I try to import chart.js module like this:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'
```

It shows an error in my terminal that said that the parsing of the module has failed.

```
./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js 554:18
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (554:18)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| };
| class DatasetController {
>   static defaults = {};
|   static datasetElementType = null;
|   static dataElementType = null;
```

Is this happening because somehow there are some deprecated packages in my node modules and the newest chart.js version is still so bleeding edge that it requires a bit workaround in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you likely are using we pack 4 which does not support static properties, so you will need to update to webpack 5, or use the babel/preset-env config with the babel loader to transpile it

Comment: can you help me with the babel/preset-env solution?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, please let me know the solution

Comment: the only solution is to downgrade chart.js and react-chart-js to previous number version.

Comment: Yes, that works. But In my case it was not feasible to update webpack(I didn't want to make any config changes in my project). 
So I downgraded chart.js version from v4 to v3.x.x as they had introduced treeshaking in v4: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/10504